# Проверка устройства на root

Tags: android, java

Мне необходимо перед установкой моего приложения проверить, есть ли на устройстве root и в если да запретить установку приложения. Можно ли это как-либо реализовать?

Comment: Сомнительное с моральной точки зрения задание у вас.

Comment: По-моему очень правильное задание. Человек хочет защитить плоды своего труда. Надеюсь, что получится.

Comment: Я думаю, что @Barmaley может помочь в этом вопросе. Он - гуру в области разработки под Андройд и наверняка уже успешно решил задачу защиты своих приложений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверить перед установкой и запретить ее Вы не сможете

В качестве решения можно сделать следующее:
при первом запуске приложения проверить есть ли root на устройстве

- есть. закрываем приложение
- нет. работаем в нормальном режиме

Как проверить на рут написано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097801/1233682)

Comment: такая проверка на рут даст результат не более 50%    
т. к. существуют и другие приложения, предоставляющие рут доступ (не только Superuser.apk)

Comment: скажу даже больше, телефон может быть порутан уже после того, как Ваше приложение будет установлено.

Я бы сделал просто - воспользовался любой аналитикой (тем же flurry.com, google analitics и подобными) и посмотрел, а сколько же там рутованых. Возможно, и не нужно ничего делать.

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, ещё можно проверять наличие рут прав этими программами http://101android.ru/kak-proverit-rut-prava/

Comment: проверить, по всей видимости, нужно из своего приложения, кодом